# JQuery dynamic input ID based on radio button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to alter the ID of an input based on the selection of a radio box.

```
<input type="text" name="judge"/>

<input type="radio" name="type" value="percent"/>Percent |
<input type="radio" name="type" value="decimal"/>Decimal
<br/>
<button type="button" id="mybutton">Check</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="output"/>
```

Clicking radio button percent or decimal will change the ID of the input box.

```
//Set the ID of the input box on radio change
$('input[name=type]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "percent") {
        $('input[name=judge]').attr('id', 'judge_percent');
    } else if ($(this).val() == "decimal") {
        $('input[name=judge]').attr('id', 'judge_decimal');
    }
});

//IF statement depending on the input ID created from the radio button
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    if ($('input[name=type]').val() == "percent") {
        value_percent = parseFloat($('#judge_percent').val());
        $('#output').html(value_percent);
    } else if ($('input[name=type]').val() == "decimal") {
        value_decimal = parseFloat($('#judge_decimal').val());
        $('#output').html(value_decimal);
    }
});
```

This only works half-way. If I check 'decimal' and click my button, I get 'NaN', as if it's not reading the input ID.

Edit:
Here is the **correct** Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6FbdJ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
} else($('input[name=type]').val() == "decimal") {
```

Should be:

```
} else if($('input[name=type]').val() == "decimal") {
```

This is what you got in the DEMO.

**Update:**

Change the selector from:

```
$('input[name=type]').val();
```

To:

```
$('input[name=type]:checked').val();
```

[**Fixed DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FbdJ/4/)

You can replace `$(this).val()` with `this.value`.

Comment: @Norse. Check the radio, then click the button... this is what your code does.

Comment: @gdoron what browser do you use

Comment: @gdoron i want to check the demo on another browser

Comment: @shareef, Tested with `IE 9` and it's working. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: @shareef. Thanks, but I can't think why won't it. jQuery is cross-browsers compability.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to create a closure for this, keeping state inside it to make your decisions:

```
(function() {
    var inputField = $('input[name=judge]'), // keep reference to the text input field
    inputType = 'percent', // set default input type to percentage
    outputBox = $('#output'); // keep reference of the output area

    $('input[name=type]').change(function() {
        // change the input type based on the value (verbatim copy)
        inputType = $(this).val();
    });

    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
        var tmp;

        if (inputType == 'percent') {
            tmp = parseFloat(inputField.val()) / 100; // make a percentage
        } else if (inputType ='decimal') {
            tmp = parseFloat(inputField.val()); // don't change anything
        }
        outputBox.text(tmp); // output the calculated value
    });
}());
```

It keeps the selected input type in a local variable and changes it based on the radio buttons; when the button is clicked it will check that local variable and make the decision based on the value.

Comment: Wow, this is good to know. I will certainly implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    if ($('input[name=type]:checked').val() == "percent") {
        value_percent = parseFloat($('#judge_percent').val() || 0);
        $('#output').html(value_percent);
    } else if ($('input[name=type]:checked').val() == "decimal") {
        value_decimal = parseFloat($('#judge_decimal').val() || 0);
        $('#output').html(value_decimal);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't work either. It will read 0 when decimal is checked regardless of what's entered in the input box.